# MySQl Error 1046 with cron that optimises tables

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

Following one of my previous questions I have started to get a error with the solution:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

Crong Job db-optimize.sh with execute permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash
chk="select concat(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.', TABLE_NAME) from information_schema.tables where data_free>0;"

for tbl in $(mysql -u root -ppass -N <<< $chk)
do
  mysql -u root -ppass -N <<< "optimize table $tbl"
done
```

I have looked up the error code and it says that I need to be in "MySQL" mode. Although this looks to be what the code is already doing.

Comment: Wouldn't `mysqlcheck --optimize --all-databases` be simpler?

Comment: No because at the moment it only optimizes the tables that are needed, your suggest method would optimize everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was being caused by not escaping the table name and because I had a table called "show"